# Limit amount of lines concatenated from list BATCH

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file that will concatenate a list but I want it to make a new line after 13 items. Below is the code that I am using to pull the data into one line but I am having issues limiting it. I have tried putting a counter on it but I am not implementing it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "var="
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (%~1) do set "var=!var!%%a "
    echo(%var%

)
```

Comment: show your (failed) code with the counter. It's probably something simple.

Comment: As you're reading lines from a file, and due to the `usebackq` option, you must use **`"%~1"`** not `%~1`. And almost as important due to your stray closing parenthesis `echo(%var%` would probably need to read `echo(!var!` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your supplied code did not really attempt the task, and you did not make clear what you meant by concatenating. What the following example does therefore, is write a new file, defined on line `4` with the content from your input file argument, `%1`, but with the content of each block of thirteen lines of input per line of output. I have separated each original line with a single whitespace character, based upon `%%a`  in your own code.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "InputFile=%~1"
Set "OutputFile=concatenated.txt"
If Not Exist "%InputFile%" Exit /B
For /F %%G In ('Copy /Z "%~f0" NUL') Do Set "CR=%%G" & (Set LF=^
% 0x0A %
)
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=0"
1>"%OutputFile%" (For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("%InputFile%"
) Do (Set /A "i += 1, # = i %% 13"
    If !#! Equ 0 (Set /P "=%%G!CR!!LF!" 0<NUL) Else Set /P "=%%G " 0<NUL))
EndLocal
```

Comment: Thank you. I have very little batch experience on top of not being very concise. Thanks again.